# How to move scripts to PATH?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to install `Whisper` by OpenAI and 7 scripts sent me this error after install:

```
  WARNING: The script lit is installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts cmake, cpack and ctest are installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tqdm is installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script isympy is installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py3 and f2py3.10 are installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts convert-caffe2-to-onnx, convert-onnx-to-caffe2 and torchrun are installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script whisper is installed in '/home/yamada/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed charset-normalizer-3.1.0 cmake-3.26.1 ffmpeg-python-0.2.0 filelock-3.10.7 jinja2-3.1.2 lit-16.0.0 llvmlite-0.39.1 mpmath-1.3.0 networkx-3.1 numba-0.56.4 numpy-1.23.5 nvidia-cublas-cu11-11.10.3.66 nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11-11.7.101 nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11-11.7.99 nvidia-cudnn-cu11-8.5.0.96 nvidia-cufft-cu11-10.9.0.58 nvidia-curand-cu11-10.2.10.91 nvidia-cusolver-cu11-11.4.0.1 nvidia-cusparse-cu11-11.7.4.91 nvidia-nccl-cu11-2.14.3 nvidia-nvtx-cu11-11.7.91 openai-whisper-20230314 regex-2023.3.23 requests-2.28.2 sympy-1.11.1 tiktoken-0.3.1 torch-2.0.0 tqdm-4.65.0 triton-2.0.0 typing-extensions-4.5.0
yamada@yamada-PC:~$
```

How do I move those 7 scripts to PATH? I don't have open the terminal from when I was installing this, but I could reinstall Ubuntu and do everything again.
I honestly don't know what to do. I would like a step by step guide on how to fix this.
Thanks

I use Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: If you're using the default (bash) shell on Ubuntu, then `/home/yamada/.local/bin` should get added to your PATH automatically the first time you login after creating it (via the default `~/.profile` file)

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With your preferred editor, can be gedit, nano...

Open `~/.bashrc`, then search the pattern `PATH`.

If it exists(Ex:):

```
export PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

add your new directory:

```
export PATH:/home/yamada/.local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

If there's no match:

```
export PATH=/home/yamada/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Then save.